# How to highlight a keyword juxtaposed to an alphabetic region start marker?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I have a syntax whereby `#J` indicates embedded JSON. This can be followed by any JSON object such as `#J[1,2,3]`.  The atom cases (Boolean, `null`, number, string) are handled as a `json_atom` region. This is a bit of a hack which says that `#J`, followed by optional whitespace, begins a region which ends on a whitespace character or closing parenthesis/bracket/brace: and the closing character is excluded.

```
syn region json_atom matchgroup=Delimiter start="#J[\t\n ]*"rs=e end="[\t\n \])}]"re=e-1 contains=[... various things ...]
```

One of the things it contains is this is `json_keyword`:

```
syn keyword json_keyword contained true false null
```

Now here is the issue: everything looks good if when there is whitespace:

```
#J true
```

However, when there is no separation

```
#Jtrue
```

the keyword is not recognized! A fallback pattern flags the `true` part in red inverse video as invalid syntax; the `#J` is colored correctly as a `Delimiter`.

Even though I used the `rs=` syntax to set the region start correctly, Vim insists that the `J` is part of the word, and does not recognize `Jtrue`.

(This is Vim 8.0, which dates back to 2016; coming from Ubuntu 18).

Answer (score 1):

I hacked it like this, by switching the keywords to a `match` rather than `keyword` definition:

```
syn match json_keyword "true\|false\|null" contained
```

This is okay because the number of keywords is small, and there are no words in JSON that are not keywords. So that is to say, now if we enter, say

```
#Jfalsehood
```

the `false` part is highlighted as a keyword, and `hood` is flagged inverse red as erroneous.  The original idea was that the whole word would be flagged, since `falsehood` isn't a keyword, but this is not bad; the user can see that a fragment of the word is a keyword.

Incidentally, the unwanted behavior that this question is about can be reproduced with `syn match` too, like this:

```
syn match json_keyword "\<\(true\|false\|null\)\>" contained
```

If we anchor these matches to the start and end of a word, Vim does not recognize them after `#J`, even though there is a region start boundary there.

It looks like a bug in Vim: Vim is doing the matching against a string which contains the full text, including the previous `J`, and does not respect the region boundary. The word anchor `\<` should match at the start of the region, but if the previous character is alphabetic, then it fails. Arguably, the matching of items contained in a region should take place as if no text exists before and after the region.

Comment: but `J` and `t` are both `'iskeyword'` characters (I assume), so `\<` can never match between them in `Jt`... (`:help /\<`)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You don't seem to acknowledge my point that, notwithstanding `iskeyword` and `\<` being well understood and good,  `J` is part of the delimiter for a syntax highlighting region, which starts after the `J`; and is correctly highlighted on its own. Items in the region should probably be matched as if they are not preceded by any text; the `J` must be deemed not to exist when we consider whether `true` is a keyword. There must be no `Jt` clump exposed to the regex engine or any other matching logic.

Comment: I think the simplest explanation is that word-boundary =/= region boundary. Attempting to put them together seems more confusing, to me.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You don't seem to acknowledge that there is a defined region which contains items. One of those items is the keyword `true`. Vim is saying that the region does not contain this keyword, which doesn't seem reasonable; the region starts with those characters, which end on a word boundary. In almost no syntax are you going to have a region which starts in the middle of a token; it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Perhaps we’re talking past each other, so I’ll disengage after this, but a keyword has word boundaries, and that isn’t met when you use `keyword` or `\<`. This is practically orthogonal to syntax regions, AFAIK.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I agree that your statements are accurate about what seems to be implemented in Vim, but that doesn't add anything to this answer. I'm looking for someone who knows if there is a way in Vim to get contained items to be matched within a region such that the matching is not allowed to look at surrounding characters in the document outside of the region. (I believe that such a behavior is intuitive, and is the precisely the semantics you want most of the time when defining a region; rarely would you want to define a region that starts or ends in the middle of a language token).